# What part of a mobile phone charger makes it safe to be charged with opposites polarity?

Tags: battery-charging, reverse-polarity

A mobile phone charger works regardless of whether the charger is the right side up or upside down. As I know, batteries should not be charged with wrong polarity. How do those chargers accomplish that?

Comment: Are you talking about the socket (AC)?

Comment: Actually that phone charger is not the actual circuit involved in charging the battery. The charger is really just a **power supply**, it makes 5 V DC and that goes (often over a USB connection) to the phone and the actual charging circuit is inside the phone. The power supply can be connected in two ways because it basically **has no polarity** on the AC (mains) side.

Comment: Alternatively you're talking about an iPhone's lighting port charger which is reversible

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The input power supply is AC therefore, on a two-prong charger, the polarity is immaterial because it's always changing/alternating at 50 or 60 times per second: -

[image]

Internally the charger uses a bridge rectifier to convert AC to DC and it is the DC that does the charging. The polarity of that DC does not change when you rotate the charger.